# pipe from ssh to windows "ssh server 'tail err.log' | tool.exe"

Tags: windows, ssh, pipe, tail

I want to live monitor a logfile generated on a remote linux host with a windows tool.

I'm looking for something like:

```
$> ssh remoteserver 'tail -F /var/log/err.log' | tool.exe
```

But on Windows. Sadly there is no way around it.

tool.exe supports reading from stdin.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this without hacking an ssh-connection directly into tool.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$> plink.exe remoteserver 'tail -f /var/log/err.log' | tool.exe
```

does the trick (plink.exe is from puTTY toolset)

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout in'side log.

A Java tool I created, able to read local and distant log files using SSH. It is fairly simple to use.

Some more explanations: https://github.com/pschweitz/insidelog/wiki

Just download the version corresponding to your operating system, or the native jar release executable within your Java Runtime (requires java 8_40 or higher):

https://github.com/pschweitz/insidelog/releases

You can find a complete documentation (embedded with and in Github's page as well)

Comment: You should disclose you are the author. Please read [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94022)

Comment: Please also include an explanation of how to use the program to accomplish the task, if it requires any special setup.